# Application in augmente reality

Tags: three.js

I have this project about development of an augmented reality application to train firefighters with three js.   I managed to create the fire scene, now the problem is i have to add a dynamic aspect to the programmed solution so as to represent the propagation of the fire as a function of the elapsed time. 
Here is below my scilab program , the propagation have to follow this model. now i've been told that i have to search how to manipulate vertices of a geometry and manipulate them with the VECTOR3 on three js but i didnt know how to solve it. any help is appreciated

[scilab program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFH58.png)

and this is the code for the fire, i ran it on visual basic [Fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1icz.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>fire fire</title>
<style>
body{margin: 0; background: #333;}
canvas{display: block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/three-particle-fire.js"></script>
<script>
//
// prepare to use
//
particleFire.install( { THREE: THREE } );

var width  = window.innerWidth,   
    height = window.innerHeight,
    clock = new THREE.Clock(),
    scene,
    camera,
    renderer,
    loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

scene  = new THREE.Scene();//
scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x333333, 8, 20 );
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, width / height, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 10;
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( width, height );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x333333 );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

scene.add( new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff ) );
scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 ) );

var fireRadius = 2;// 43 45 parametre de la geometry fire
var fireHeight = 20;
var particleCount = 5200;

/
var geometry0 = new particleFire.Geometry( fireRadius, fireHeight, particleCount ); 

var material0 = new particleFire.Material( { color: 0xff2200 , wireframe: true } );
material0.setPerspective( camera.fov, height );
var particleFireMesh0 = new THREE.Points( geometry0, material0 );
particleFireMesh0.position.set( 0, -1, 0 );
scene.add( particleFireMesh0 );

      
var groundColor = textureLoader.load( 'grass_diffuse.png' );//85  95 creation ground et l ajouter a la scene
groundColor.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
groundColor.wrapS = groundColor.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

var ground = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 1, 1 ),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: groundColor } )
);
ground.position.y = -1;
ground.rotation.x = THREE.Math.degToRad( -90 );
scene.add( ground );
particleFire = [];

( function update () {

    var delta = clock.getDelta();
    var elapsed = clock.getElapsedTime(); 
  particleFireMesh0.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true; 
  

    requestAnimationFrame( update );

    particleFireMesh0.material.update( delta * 0.1 );  

    
    camera.position.set(6,5,10);
    camera.lookAt( particleFireMesh0.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

} )();

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {

    var width  = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );

    particleFireMesh0.material.setPerspective( camera.fov, height );
    //particleFireMesh1.material.setPerspective( camera.fov, height );//
    

} );
console.log("vertices: ", geometry0.vertices);
console.log( geometry0.isBufferGeometry );

  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Please do not display an image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). We need real examples of code so people can reproduce your problem to get you a solution.

Comment: I didnt upload code's images , the image it's the result that i've got from the code